# Generating a sequence of MIDI numbers from an arbitrary MIDI file in python

Tags: python, midi

I'm in the process of creating an app that reads a sheet and then generates a sequence of piano keys to be pressed in order for the sheet to be "played". I managed to get the MusicXML or MIDI file for my sheets. 
MIDI format is exactly what I need since there's a one to one correspondence between a MIDI number and a key on the piano (according to http://newt.phys.unsw.edu.au/jw/notes.html) and it simpler than mapping each note of in the MusicXML file to a key. 
However I cannot access MIDI numbers themselves and MIDI editors (like MuseScore) only show the notation not the actual numbers. 
Is there a way to generate the sequence of MIDI numbers for a MIDI file in python?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading a MIDI file in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933938/reading-a-midi-file-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the python-midi library (https://github.com/vishnubob/python-midi) to parse a midi file and access the midi-data

have a look at the midi-dump script (in the script folder)